# Command-line CVS update and local delete of a directory

Tags: command-line, cvs

I accidentally locally deleted a directory in a CVS repository, which I'm also managing with mercurial locally.  I can `hg revert` the directory, but I've got hg set up to ignore the CVS directories, so there's no CVS directory.  CVS is freaking out every time I try to do a commit (it's a trivial directory that was removed), unless I specifically target the files to be committed.

I've tried `CVS update` and that's not getting it done.  Can anyone make a suggestion?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
cvs update -d
```

The `-d` flag tells CVS to look for new directories. By default it will not automatically pick up new directories during updates just in case you intentionally omitted particular sub-trees of your repository during checkout.

Personally I always want the `-d` option to be used so I added this option (and a few others) to my `~/.cvsrc` configuration:

```
cvs -q
checkout -P
update -d -P
diff -u
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `cvs checkout` to check the directory out again. Just go to the root of your repository and use the command to only check out that specific directory.